# Suppress nonstandard pages in book-in-book citation

Tags: biblatex

I need to cite a book in an anthology that does not use standard page numbers.

In the bibliography, the page numbers for the whole work should be given.

In the citations, only the page numbers that I am referring to should be listed. Ordinarily this is done with the option citepages=omit. Unfortunately, when the pages in the "postnote" field are nonstandard, this option does not seem to work.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
                style=verbose-ibid,
                citepages=omit,
                ibidpage=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{pages.bib}

@bookinbook{a,
  author    = {An Author},
  title     = {A Book With Nonstandard Pages},
  booktitle = {A Bigger Book},
  pages     = {123A--131D},
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{pages.bib}

\begin{document}

I want to cite this book with only the pages I am referring to.\footcite[130B]{a}

\end{document}
```

The current result in the footnote is as follows:

> <sup>1</sup> An Author. *A Book With Nonstandard Pages*. In: *A Bigger Book*, 123A–131D, 130B.

The desired result is

> <sup>1</sup> An Author. *A Book With Nonstandard Pages*. In: *A Bigger Book*, 130B.

(The fact that it does not add "pp" is OK with me.)

Any ideas for how to do this?

Comment: You could tell `biblatex` that "A", "B", "C" and "D" are indeed standard page fields with `\DeclareNumChars{ABCD}`. Or use `citepages=suppress`, then the `pages` will always be suppressed.

Comment: It worked for most of them. Is there a way to suppress the pages for just one citation? (I have one that is particularly complex, and `\DeclareNumChars` trick won't work for it.)

Comment: There is not, as far as I know. What does the complex entry look like, if I might ask? Because there are other commands similar to `\DeclareNumChars` that might help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [guide to the `verbose-ibid` style](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/71-style-verbose-ibid.pdf) states

> `citepages=omit` suppresses the `pages`/`pagetotal` in the third case only [the third case is when cite is called with a `postnote` that passes the `\ifpages` test].
>   They are still printed if there is no `postnote` or if the `postnote` is
>   not a number or range.

You can read more about the `\ifpages` test on p. 177 (§4.6.2 *Stand-alone Tests*) of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)

So you have two options here

1. Convince `biblatex` that "A", "B", "C" and "D" are actually valid page "numbers"
2. Always suppress the `pages` field, regardless of the nature of the `postnote`.

### Solution 1

You can use `\DeclareNumChars{ABCD}` to make `biblatex` treat "numbers" including those characters as numbers.
Consequently `postnote`s such as `113B` will now pass the `\ifpages` test.
(Another upside is that now the `pages` and `pagetotal` fields containing those characters will have the "pp." added as well).

Read more about `\DeclareNumChars` and related commands in §4.6.4 *Miscellaneous Commands*, pp. 186 sq. of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

### Solution 2

Or you can use `citepages=suppress` instead of `citepages=omit` (again the [guide to the `verbose-ibid` style](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/71-style-verbose-ibid.pdf)):

> `citepages=suppress` unconditionally suppresses the `pages`/`pagetotal`
>   fields in citations, regardless of the `postnote`.

MWE for solution 1

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
                style=verbose-ibid,
                citepages=omit,
                ibidpage=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@bookinbook{a,
  author    = {An Author},
  title     = {A Book With Nonstandard Pages},
  booktitle = {A Bigger Book},
  pages     = {131A--123D},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareNumChars{ABCD}
\begin{document}
I want to cite this book with only the pages I am referring to.\footcite[1311B]{a}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had one citation in which I had to suppress the pages manually. See my answer for the code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem as follows:

In the preamble, I added the following to allow letters to be considered as "numbers":

```
\DeclareNumChars{ABCDE}
```

I added the following hook before the complex entry:

```
\AtNextCitekey{\clearfield{pages}}
```

This will suppress the `pages` field for the very next citation (and only that one).

Comment: `\AtNextCite{\clearfield{pages}\clearfield{pagetotal}}` should be enough.

Comment: No, I just tried it. The "minimum" required seems to be `\AtNextCite{\renewbibmacro*{cite:full:citepages}\clearfield{pages}\clearfield{pagetotal}}}`. I have edited my answer

Comment: You are absolutely right, it should have been `\AtNextCitekey{\clearfield{pages}}`, if we use `\AtNextCite` the bibliography data is not yet available, it only comes available once we use `\AtNextCitekey`.

Comment: Yes, that works. I edited my answer with the simpler macro.