# Biblatex ignore postnode in \cites

Tags: biblatex, citing

I want to have a flag to ignore all page numbers that are given to citations within the document. The goal is that these two commands show the same result:

`\cite[1]{mykey}` 
`\cite{mykey}`

I achieved this for the `\cite` command using the following statements:

`\let\oldcite\cite`
`\renewcommand{\cite}[2][]{\oldcite[]{#2}}`

How would I do this for the `\cites` command?
The goal is to get the same result from these two commands:

`\cites[1]{mykey}[10-15]{mykey2}` 
`\cites{mykey}{mykey2}`

Thanks

Comment: Could I interest you in a simple `\renewbibmacro*{postnote}{}` (and maybe `\renewbibmacro*{multipostnote}{}`) to get rid of the page numbers instead of your redefinition of `\cite`. The upside of this solution is that it works for all `\cite` commands (`\footcite`, `\autocite` and friends) alike and at once.

Comment: Way better than the redefinition of \cite. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two alternative solutions in one: either redefine the `\cites` command, or use the new pair of commands `\pageson` and `\pagesoff` to affect all the following `\cite` commands as hinted by moewe. The suppression of page numbers is achieved by clearing the field `postnote`. I learned about `biblatex` fields from [Suppress nonstandard pages in book-in-book citation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/174295/23160).

[image: Result of example code]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{mykey,
  author = {Author, A},
  title =     {Title A},
  publisher = {Books A},
  year =      {2000},
}
@Book{mykey2,
  author = {Author, B},
  title =     {Title B},
  publisher = {Books B},
  year =      {2001},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% Commands for setting page references on and off
\newcommand{\pageson}{\renewcommand{\conditionalpages}{}}
\newcommand{\pagesoff}{\renewcommand{\conditionalpages}{\clearfield{postnote}}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\conditionalpages}
\newcommand{\conditionalpages}{}

% Renewed \cites command
\let\savedcites\cites
\newcommand{\oldcites}{\pageson\savedcites}
\renewcommand{\cites}{\pagesoff\savedcites}

\begin{document}

\section*{Renewed command}
Using \verb+\cites+~\cites[1]{mykey}[10-15]{mykey2},
\verb+\oldcites+~\oldcites[1]{mykey}[10-15]{mykey2}.

\section*{Setting page references off}
\pagesoff
\verb+\autocites+~\autocites[1]{mykey}[10-15]{mykey2},
\verb+\footcites+~\footcites[1]{mykey}[10-15]{mykey2}.

\section*{Setting page references on}
\pageson
\verb+\autocites+~\autocites[1]{mykey}[10-15]{mykey2},
\verb+\footcites+~\footcites[1]{mykey}[10-15]{mykey2}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```